# Angular 9 MatDialog not able to use Imported FormsModule or ReactiveFormsModule

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 9 and as part of the app a Dialog box opens to take in a string from a Form. In app.module I have both `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`. These are both working perfectly fine throughout the app. However, if I attempt to use them in a `MatDialog` component, I receive these errors:

> error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
>
> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

The html for the form is:

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Add Special</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
<mat-form-field>
  <div mat-label>Special</div>
  <input required matInput type ="text" placeholder="" [formControl]="specialText">
</mat-form-field>
```

As said, the above code works in any other component that isn't a Dialog component, however it simply doesn't even compile while it is in a Dialog component. All imports seem to be present as per any documentation.

Comment: Got any stackblitz working example? it would be easy to debug the issue then.

Comment: @C.Brown Import `MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,` this module

Comment: Abhishek. Both have been imported, certainly would normally be the problem but all there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed.

The issue was unrelated to imports. When the project was moved from Angular 8 to Angular 9 and EntryComponents was removed. The module that is acting as the MatDialog was no longer listed in Declarations in app.module. Once that was added back in the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your import

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

For Angular 9+ onwards

Everywhere you import `MatDialog`